# TypeScript: async generator

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, generator

I'd like to have a function like this:

```
export async function* iterateDir(dir: string) {
    let list = await fs.readdir(dir); // fs-promise implementation of readdir
    for (let file of list) {
        yield file;
    }
}
```

Which I would use like:

```
for (let file in iterateDir(dir)) {
    processFile(file);
}
```

This doesn't work because a function cannot be both async and a generator.

How would I structure the code to achieve the same?

1. If I change the `await fs.readdir` to callbacks, I assume the outer for..of loop would not wait.
2. If I get rid of the generator and the directory is huge, `iterateDir()` will be slow.

For reference: [async generator function proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#async-generator-functions)

Comment: If your async work is done *before* your generator work, then you can just make them different functions.

Comment: The point is that the generator itself needs to be async (it awaits filesystem operations).

Comment: Generators cannot be asynchronous (yet). The code you posted doesn't need to be an asynchronous generator; it can be split into an asynchronous part and a generator part.

Comment: Well, in my specific case, `iterateDir` would be recursive. For every `file`, there would be a detection whether it's a directory or not, and if it is, call `iterateDir` recursively. In which case I don't know how to split the async and generation functionality. Which is the point of the question..

Comment: In that case, I recommend using observables (Rx.JS).

Comment: This is the only place in the app I have this problem, isn't there a solution not involving introducing a new library, learning it etc.?

Comment: Not for TypeScript. If this was Flow + Babel, sure, but not TS.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is supported in **TypeScript 2.3** -  [tracked issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11326)

It introduces a few new types, notably:

```
interface AsyncIterable<T> {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterator<T>;
}
```

but most importantly it also introduces `for await ... of`

```
for await (const line of readLines(filePath)) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

where

```
async function* readLines(path) {
   //await and yield ...
}
```

Be aware that if you want to try this you will need to configure typescript to let it know you have run-time support (add "esnext.asynciterable" to `lib` list) you will probably need to polyfill `Symbol.asyncIterator`. see [TS2318: Cannot find global type 'AsyncIterableIterator' - async generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43694281/1657476)

Answer (score -3):

Stream of future values is called `Observable`. So the most natural thing is to use a library like RxJS or most.js. If you don't want to introduce a new complex library only to use it once, use the good old approach with callbacks:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("mz/fs");

async function listDirectory(dirName, cb, level = 0) {
  for (let fileName of await fs.readdir(dirName)) {
    let absName = path.resolve(dirName, fileName);
    let isDirectory = (await fs.stat(absName)).isDirectory();
    cb({ level, fileName });
    if (isDirectory) {
      await listDirectory(absName, cb, level + 1);
    }
  }
}

listDirectory(".", ({ level, fileName }) => {
  console.log(" ".repeat(level) + fileName);
});
```

If you try to convert the callback to some better abstraction, you will rediscover RxJS sooner or later. It's similar to converting one-shot callbacks to promises.

Comment: The difference is that iterables are "pull" (caller requests next value) while Observables are "push" (called function determines when a new value is available and notifies the caller).  In the OP's example, they really want a Promise (push) that resolves with a generator function (pull).

Comment: I was actually trying to use Observable and failed to write code that would be sensibly simple. The code I got was absurdly complex and I gave up on Observables. Then I was trying to find code examples and found none pretty much.