# TS2318: Cannot find global type 'AsyncIterableIterator' - async generator

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have an async generator:

```
async function* foo() {
  yield "wait...";
  await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 900));
  yield new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>r("okay!"), 100));
}

async function main() {
  for await (let item of foo()) {
    let result = await item;
    console.log(result);
  }
}

main();
```

but with typescript 2.3 this give me errors:

> error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'AsyncIterableIterator'.
>   example.ts(10,26):
>
> error TS2504: Type must have a 'Symbol.asyncIterator' method that returns an async iterator.

How can this error be fixed and how can you run the async generator?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) is an `esnext` feature; so you must explicitly target `esnext`, *or* add the `esnext.asynciterable` library, for typescript to support the syntax. However, typescript does **not** deal with the implementation of Symbols at runtime at present, so you need to polyfill.

#### Polyfill + Down-Compile

Add `"esnext.asynciterable"` to `lib` in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [      
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  }
}
```

you can polyfill `Symbol.asyncIterator` by simply creating a new Symbol before you do anything else.

```
if(Symbol["asyncIterator"] === undefined) ((Symbol as any)["asyncIterator"]) = Symbol.for("asyncIterator");
```

Compile and run as normal.

This should also be applied in any reusable packages - ideally on the very first line of your module's `main` script

#### Native Support

If you are targetting node 7 and above, you can actually just run async iterators natively with a flag.

Set `target: "esnext"` in tsconfig.json, compile, and run with

```
node --harmony_async_iteration example.js
```

Same is available for ts-node too, where you can run it directly.

```
ts-node --harmony_async_iteration example.ts
```

With Node 9; it has been staged under the `--harmony` flag

As of Node 10; it is enabled by default.

#### Warning:

I've experienced some compatibility issues when you mix typescript compiled async-gen code with babel's down-compile in a webpack bundle. It *may* be due how babel's polyfill looks for the symbol and then creates one if it is missing. The compatibility issue is that it would appear the babel code doesn't think the typescript (+Symbol polyfill) code has a  `Symbol.asyncIterable` key-entry.

Could also avoid the problem by using the same Symbol polyfill that babel's plugin will use:

```
import "core-js/modules/es7.symbol.async-iterator"
```

Comment: thank you for the great explanation. one question, when i'm using the "Polyfill + Down-Compile" instructions, I had to add the asyncIterator symbol with `(Symbol as any)["asyncIterator"]` instead of `(<any>Symbol)["asyncIterator"]` to not get tsc errors -- why is that?

Comment: using react or tsx files? I'll update anyhow; thanks. :)

Comment: I'd still like to solve `Cannot find global type 'AsyncIterableIterator'`

Comment: @reconbot Pretty sure you need `"lib": [... , "esnext.asynciterable"]` entry in tsconfig.json. Then it should load up the typings for `AsyncIterableIterator` (try restarting vscode after you do it as sometimes the language service can get stuck).