# Error while running Angular Application with @azure/storage-blob

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm following
[Adding File to Azure Storage Blob from Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533341/adding-file-to-azure-storage-blob-from-angular)
to save files on azure storage but im getting following error when i run serve command.

````
node_modules/@azure/abort-controller/types/src/AbortSignal.d.ts(40,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@azure/abort-controller/types/src/AbortSignal.d.ts(46,16): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@azure/core-paging/types/3.1/core-paging.d.ts(28,13): error TS2339: Property 'asyncIterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@azure/core-paging/types/3.1/core-paging.d.ts(32,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterableIterator'.```

My Angular version is "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5" And "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.3.0".
Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to target `esnext` for `Symbol.asyncIterator` to work. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43694282/10417839) for more information.