# How to call one asynchronous function after another?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, callback

This is what I have:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._addServ.getDefaultAddress().subscribe((res)=>{
      if(res.status){
        //I need these next two functions to finish their async API requests 
        //before selectNormalDelivery is called
        this.selectShippingAddress();
        this.selectBillingAddress();
        this.selectNormalDelivery();
      }
    })
  }
```

I need `selectShippingAddress` and `selectBillingAddress` to finish their calls, and then for `selectNormalDelivery` to be called. How can I accomplish this? I don't want to convert them into promises as they're called other times without needing to be chained. Is this something involving `.then`?

This is the code for the functions:

```
  selectShippingAddress(){
    this.addressService.setShippingAddresses(this.cartService.shippingAddress.address_id).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('Set shipping address!')
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Failed to set shipping address')
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  selectBillingAddress(){
    this.addressService.setPaymentAddresses(this.cartService.billingAddress.address_id).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('Set billing address!')
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Failed to set billing address')
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

If I try a `.then`, I get the error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.`, which makes sense as I'm not trying to return anything, I just need them to complete their calls for the API's sake.

Suggestions?

Comment: Then you need to change those functions to return something: a promise, if you want to use `.then`; or an observable. Or they could accept a callback, but adding in another async paradigm probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not very familiar with creating and subscribing to custom observables. Could I also try using the approach of same component Event Emitters? And for the functions to listen to each other?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on that, then, it's an important part of the way Angular handles most async things.

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596641/is-it-a-good-practice-using-observable-with-async-await

Comment: check my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to listen to one observable (from `getDefaultAddress()`), then process two other observables (`this.addressService.setShippingAddresses()` and `this.addressService.setPaymentAddresses()`) and after that call function `selectNormalDelivery()`.

You could do so by using RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap), [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError), [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operators and [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin). Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this._addServ.getDefaultAddress().pipe(
    switchMap((res) => {        // <-- map the observable from `getDefaultAddress()` to another observable
      if(res.status) {
        return forkJoin([       // <-- `forkJoin` emits only after the observables complete
          this.selectShippingAddress(), this.selectBillingAddress()
        ])
      }
    })
  ).subscribe(response => {
    this.selectNormalDelivery()
  })
}

selectShippingAddress() {
  return this.addressService.setShippingAddresses(this.cartService.shippingAddress.address_id).pipe(
    tap((res) => {            // <-- `tap` doesn't alter the response
      console.log('Set shipping address!')
      console.log(res);
    }),
    catchError((err) => {     // <-- `catchError` must return an observable
      console.log('Failed to set shipping address')
      console.log(err);
      return EMPTY;
    }))
}


selectShippingAddress() {
  return this.addressService.setPaymentAddresses(this.cartService.shippingAddress.address_id).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      console.log('Set billing address!')
      console.log(res);
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      console.log('Failed to set billing address')
      console.log(err);
      return EMPTY;
    }))
}
```

Comment: I like this! Not only did you give me a solution, but also some concepts (Tap, switchMap, etc) to further research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._addServ.getDefaultAddress().subscribe((res)=>{
      if(res.status){
        //I need these next two functions to finish their async API requests 
        //before selectNormalDelivery is called
        forkJoin([this.selectShippingAddress(),this.selectBillingAddress()].subscribe(() => {

            this.selectNormalDelivery();
        });
      }
    })
  }

 selectShippingAddress(){
    return this.addressService.setShippingAddresses(this.cartService.shippingAddress.address_id).pipe(map((res) => {
      console.log('Set shipping address!')
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Failed to set shipping address')
      console.log(err);
    }));
  }

  selectBillingAddress(){
    return this.addressService.setPaymentAddresses(this.cartService.billingAddress.address_id).pipe(map((res) => {
      console.log('Set billing address!')
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Failed to set billing address')
      console.log(err);
    }));
  }
```