# Caveats regarding using async/await in angular project

Tags: angular, async-await, promise

Recent angular project has `promise` everywhere so I started to use `async/await`. Not sure this is just syntax thing.

The component and service both seem fine with it.

So even `(click)="asyncFunc()"` is also seemingly OK.

```
async asyncFunc() {
    this.data = await this.someService.asyncFun();
}
```

I want to know if anyone has experience with this.

Anything down the road that might be a problem? Just guessing here, maybe an `async function kept waiting` then that component or that service involved might become `hard to die` when route changes.

Comment: better to switch to observables instead as they are cancellable and you can kill them when required

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, observables are a wonderful way to write reactive and clean code.

Async/Await is just syntactic sugar.

**But** no one can argue that async/await makes code more precise and readable.

It always dependends on your use case.

Check these:

[Is it a good practice using Observable with async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596641/is-it-a-good-practice-using-observable-with-async-await)

[What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables)