# Angular - How to get an object map from httpClient and return it in a method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple Angular Application witch get values from Spring-Boot backend

```
export class UserDto {

  constructor(
    public login: string,
    public password: string,
  ) {
  }
}

export class AuthService {
   private url = '....';

getUser() {
   return this.http.get<UserDto[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

and than in my component i have function which create map of values:

```
constructor(private auth: AuthService){}

private getMapOfUsers() {
    const priceListMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res => {
      res.map(item => {
          priceListMap.set(item.login, item.password);
        }
      );
    });
    return priceListMap;
  }
```

When i use:

```
getLoginData() {
    console.log(this.getMapOfUsers());
  }
```

I have in console result:

[image]

the login from UserDto is crossed in red

I have `Map(0)` but in size it's 18... when i try get real size this map i have size = 0. I can see objects in "Entries" but I can't get them in any way.

```
getLoginData() {
    console.log(this.getMapOfUsers().size);  // result = 0
  }
```

How can I get a solution that I could map these objects, then how to find the password using the given key as login ????

Comment: You might need to read up on the async nature of Observables. You are returning priceListMap before the the ons emits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here,

```
private getMapOfUsers() {
    const priceListMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res => {
      res.map(item => {
          priceListMap.set(item.login, item.password);
        }
      );
    });
    return priceListMap;
  }
```

The code in the subscription is going to fire asynchronously so it is likely that you are returning priceListMap before its value is set.

There are a number of ways to handle this, the best one is to push priceListMap directly onto your template using the [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe. You can also wait on the return value with an [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) pattern, but this can get a little messy in my opinion. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596641/is-it-a-good-practice-using-observable-with-async-await) to see how async/await works with observables as well.