# Promise.all not waiting to complete the requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, request-promise

```
await Promise.all(
  endpoints.map((endpoint) =>
    this.httpService.get(endpoint).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return response.data['result'];
      }),
    ),
  ),
).then(
  axios.spread((...allData) => {
    allData.forEach((res) =>
      res.subscribe((res) => {
        apiFeedBack.push(res);
        console.log(apiFeedBack);
      }),
    );
  }),
);
```

**While debugging it is skipping promise.all execution and directly returns undefined as response. What am i missing here**

Comment: I don't think so you should be using observables and promises at the same time.

Comment: If you want to use `Promise.all` you will have to convert observable into promise and return it from your `array.map`

Comment: @AliHussnain I am new to nestjs, Could you provide the code snippet for conversion of observable to promise for above code

Comment: Whatsup with the `map` function *inside* the `pipe` function? Are you receiving an array as a result from `httpService.get`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are using await don't use `then`. This is how it be like:

```
const promiseAll = async () => {
try {
  const res = await Promise.all(promises);
  return res;
} catch (e) {
 console.error(e);
}
}
```

Now, we need to get the values from the promises using await, Also, it would be clean if you write it this way:

```
const endpoints_Promises = endPoints.map(endPoint => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.httpService.get(endpoint).pipe(
    map((response) => {
      resolve(response.data['result']);
    })
   ) 
 })
})
try {
const responses = await Promise.all(endpoints_Promises);
responses.forEach(data =>  console.log(data));
} catch (e) {
   console.error(`Error occured: ${e}`);
}
```

Comment: From where is resolve function coming up?

Comment: You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) link.

Answer (score 0):

folks as you may know that `@nestjs/axios` in NestJS returns observable rather then promise however this is not the case of `axios`.

So in case you need to make observable asynchronous you will need to convert it to promise, although it's not a recommended way and `.toPromise()` is deprecated in the latest version of `@nestjs/axios`.

```
Promise.all(
  return endpoints.map((endpoint) =>
    this.httpService.get(endpoint).toPromise(),
  ),
).then((responses)=> {
   // here you get the resolved promises responses array
})
```

Check this out to learn more about [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#fulfillment) fulfillment.

Check this out for more information if you should be using observable async/await [Is it a good practice using Observable with async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596641/is-it-a-good-practice-using-observable-with-async-await)

Comment: `toPromise` will be deprecated soon. Also, You can't use await and then together. This is anti-pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the array of promises received from the map function as below:

```
await Promise.all(
  return endpoints.map((endpoint) =>
    this.httpService.get(endpoint).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return response.data['result'];
      }),
    ),
  ),
).then(
  axios.spread((...allData) => {
    allData.forEach((res) =>
      res.subscribe((res) => {
        apiFeedBack.push(res);
        console.log(apiFeedBack);
      }),
    );
  }),
)
```

Comment: This will cause a `SyntaxError` as the `Promise.all` function expects an expression and not a `return` keyword. The problem lies in that there are no promises returned *inside* the `map` function.