# how to sequence run multiple observables with different data types and logics

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hello guys in my case i have a form that includes multiple select types,options of these inputs come form API and then feed the emitted data from HTTP request observable to my `FormGroup` every thing works fine by now.

then decided to add edit feature to my app, so user can edit related entity with the same component. so i need to run two observable one after each and i need to first one to be completed to run another one.

it means i need to call `getFormFieldData` form my service feed its emitted value to my `formGroup` then after this i need to call `getUserEntityData()` and feed its emitted data to my `formGroup` initial value, after this user can start editing.

there must be a `rxjs` operator to do this i read some articles about concat but types of my emitted data are different and also the logic.

tnx for helping me.

Comment: `switchMap` with `pipe`, or `firstValueFrom` with `await` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71136301/12914833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) on the high level it will look like

```
doAction() {
    // disable form
    this.service.getFormFieldData().pipe(
       switchMap((response) => {
           this.formGroup.patchValue(response);
           return this.service.getUserEntityData().pipe(
               map((response2) => {
                    this.formGroup.patchValue(response2);
               })
           );
       })
    ).subscribe(() => {
        // enable form
    });
}
```